# Group Clone and Rename Tables in MySQL5.1

Tags: mysql

I have multiple tables which need to be droped and replaced in my crowded MySQL5.1 DB.

I want to clone tables with names like `2015-11-17` `2015-11-18`... `2015-11-30` and rename them with names `2015-12-17` `2015-12-18`... `2015-12-30` like below :

```
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|        original table name   |        cloned table name     |
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
| <prefix>_2015-11-17_<suffix> | <prefix>_2015-12-17_<suffix> |
| <prefix>_2015-11-18_<suffix> | <prefix>_2015-12-18_<suffix> |
| ...                          | ...                          |
| <prefix>_2015-11-30_<suffix> | <prefix>_2015-12-30_<suffix> |
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

How to do this efficiantly in phpMyAdmin environment.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Comment: How many tables? What about [RENAME TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/rename-table.html)?